# Registering GoatCounter analytic event for audio playback with useEffect causes page to refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, goatcounter

I have a React component for an HTML audio embed. I want to track using GoatCounter when somebody clicks on play, following [this documentation](https://www.goatcounter.com/help/events). However, when I introduce the GoatCounter code, it causes a the page to reload when the play button is pressed. On the reloaded page, the play button works OK.

Here is my component

```
const AudioEmbed = (props) => {

  const { src, children, title } = props;
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const onPlay = function (e) {
  console.log("Playing audio");
    window.goatcounter.count({
      path: path => `audio-${path}`,
      title: {src},
      event: true,
    })
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.addEventListener("play", onPlay);
  });

  return (
    <figure>
      <audio controls preload="metadata" src={src} className={css.audio} aria-label={title} ref={ref} />
      {children && <figcaption>{children}</figcaption>}
    </figure>
  );
}
```

For now I've disabled the `window.goatcounter.count` call which stops the page refresh, but stops me being able to count the number of plays.

I'm using Gatsby 5.10 with React 18.2. How can I register this event without the page refreshing?